# How to upgrade Kubuntu from 19.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

I am having issue upgrading my Kubuntu from 19.04 to 20.04. I have tried to find a solution, but nothing seems to be working for me. W

```
test@test:~/Document$
[sudo] password for name:  
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Can someone help me to upgrade Kubuntu?

Comment: Try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release/91821#91821

Comment: The intended path from 19.04 was to the next release, 19.10 which is now EOL and thus the intended upgrade path is gone.  LTS releases allow you to upgrade to the next release OR *skip* to the next LTS release, however 19.04 was **not** a LTS release, so it's intended release path was to 19.10.  You can upgrade via re-install (something-else, use existing partitions but do **not** format) still.

Comment: @guiverc thanks for you answer. Can you explain a bit more about re-install?

Comment: You can use the *something-else* (`ubiquity`, *manual partitioning* on `calamares`, I forget what the Kubuntu skin calls it; maybe *manual*) option to select your existing partitions. ENSURE you don't have format checked (that box is key! as sets a flag on install as well as indicating if format is selected). The installer will note your installed packages (ie. those added post-install), erase system directories, install system, then attempt to add back the additional packages noted earlier (if available on new release), without touching user files (unless format was used).

Comment: That works really well with desktop apps, as they store *conf* files in $HOME, however note if you are using server apps (that can store configs in system directories), as system directories are wiped those programs will require restoration of data (we all backup anyway). If you've stored fonts/pixmaps/etc in system directories for global use, they'll need restoration, but most desktop users use $HOME for those anyway.

Comment: the feature I describe has been there decade+, however as users regularly file bugs about it not coping/restoring 3rd party apps (it was designed for Ubuntu repositories only) the feature is being withdrawn.. but  if I recall correctly that was in the *groovy* cycle so won't impact your wanted *focal* (it worked with 20.04 media, I assume so still with 20.04.1 media but I don't recall testing it which was release post announcement of removal of that function).