# Ubuntu USB keyboard and mouse driver fail after upgrade

Tags: drivers, upgrade, usb, keyboard

Since Ubuntu 19.04 is eol, I struggled a bit to upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10. It finally worked, but I was unable to upgrade to 20.04. Then I tried to reboot my computer. After reboot, the mouse and the keyboard are not working. I tried USB keyboard and ps2 keyboard, but not seems to work. I don't really know what to do now. How Can I install driver if I can login. any advise on how to handle this. I can reinstall because all my password are on chrome. I and stuck now.

Comment: It's not clear to me release you are running?  If the upgrade to 20.04 failed, then you're using 19.10?  Ubuntu 19.10 is EOL & thus off-topic here now.   If it's a desktop, you can re-install without loosing browser setup, but backups should of course always be done as mistakes are easily made (ie. formatting the dis and thus erasing the data in error)

Comment: @guiverc thanks for you comment. can you give me tuto that explain how to re-install without loosing my browser history and password ?  I am currently running Ubuntu 19.10, but when reboot every seems to works normally except keyboard and mouse are not working, so I cannot log in. but before reboot, my I was on 19.10

Comment: You're off-topic here, but refer to last comments in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296537/how-to-upgrade-kubuntu-from-19-04-to-20-04  It can be used to *upgrade via re-install* and allows you to skip/change releases as well as re-install the same release.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution. Basically, I restarted in recovery mode, set up my network. In my case, the DNS server was missing. so I had to enter `namerserver 8.8.8.8`. Once the internet connection was Ok, I just entered: `sudo apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-all` and restarted and it worked.